# Add NSViews to NSScrollView programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsscrollview

I am trying to add some `NSView`s to my `NSScrollView`:

```
NSView *v = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];

NSTextField *t1 = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
[t1 setStringValue:@"test1"];

NSTextField *t2 = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
[t1 setStringValue:@"test2"];

[v addSubview:t1];
[v addSubview:t2];

[[_scrollView documentView] addSubview:v];
```

I also tried `[_scrollView addSubview:v]`.

Nothing seems to happen, even this code gets executed without errors. The `NSScrollView` seems empty. scrollView `IBOutlet` is connected. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The following code worked for me! 
Don't forget to add constraints for the views.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

let mainWindow: NSWindow = {
    let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(10, 10, 700, 700), styleMask: .resizable, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.isOpaque = true
    window.styleMask.insert(.miniaturizable)
    window.styleMask.insert(.titled)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    window.title = "My Playground"
    window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    return window
}()

let scrollView: NSScrollView = {
    let scrollView = NSScrollView()
    scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
}()

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    let v: NSView = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 100))

    let t1: NSTextField = NSTextField()
    t1.stringValue = "test1"

    let t2: NSTextField = NSTextField()
    t2.stringValue = "test2"

    v.addSubview(t1)
    v.addSubview(t2)

    t1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    t1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    t1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.rightAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true

    t2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: t1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    t2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    t2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.rightAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true

    t1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    t2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    mainWindow.contentView = scrollView

    mainWindow.contentView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    scrollView.documentView = v
    v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    v.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    v.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}}
```